# microtime() возвращает отрицательное число

Tags: php

```
<?php
$time_start_script = microtime();
//PHP CODE
$time_stop_script = microtime();
echo $time_stop_script - $time_start_script;
?>
```

Почему мне иногда возвращает отрицательное число? Эта штука по идее должна замерять время выполнения скрипта

Comment: эта "штука" не предназначена для измерения времени работы скрипта. Читайте документацию.

Comment: @KoVadim  

    Example #1 Timing script execution with microtime()
Самый первый пример с php.net

Comment: microtime может кешировать свои вызовы.

Comment: @KoVadim а где можно найти информацию об этом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
microtime(true);
```

В [доках](http://php.su/functions/?microtime) много интересного кстати :)